# What's the status of Cosmic Inflation after the BICEP2 debacle?

Tags: cosmological-inflation

I've read that the gravitational waves supposedly discovered by the BICEP2 observatory last year (and touted as evidence for cosmic inflation) weren't actually gravitational waves, but some sort of local phenomenon.

That being said, what's the current status of cosmic inflation? Is the theory dead? Or is there still a possibility to find gravitational waves somewhere once all the noise is subtracted?

Comment: Inflation is certainly still alive as a theory. The failure of bicep2 only means that the *proof* of the theory is still not found, not that the theory itself is dead.

Comment: Pretty close to a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/165490/